# I am using 3d modeling softwares. Can Ubuntu 13.10 is good for me....?

Tags: installation, drivers, alternative

I have a `HP Pavilion g6 2230tx` laptop with `Radeon 7670m` graphic card.

I am frustrated to using windows now. So I think to upgrade my windows platform to linux.

1. My question is can I use `autodesk maya`, `autodesk 3d max`, `Adobe
   photoshop`, `Adobe illustrator` type software in Ubuntu without any
   problems?
2. If yes, which software extension support ubuntu?
3. If I install ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop then is there a graphic driver available for my  Radeon 7670m card?

Answer (score 0):

Using a compatibility layer like [Wine](http://www.winehq.org) you may be able to run them on Ubuntu. But they can be really instable and lack some of the features the have on a real Windows.

There are many opensource alternatives for such programs, like GIMP (The GNU Image Manipulation Program), which you could use instead of Adobe Photoshop, or Inkscape instead of Illustrator. I'm sure you'll find an alternative for each of the programs you're using on Windows. You can get them easily via the Ubuntu Software Center.

As for your Radeon, just try using Ubuntu form bootstick or DVD. (this won't install it, it's just a Ubuntu started from an external disc.)

Comment: If this answe was helpful, please accept it as such